# Unitary matrix with columns conjugate of each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I am currently looking at a $4 \times 4$ unitary matrix where i have two rows which are conjugates of the other two rows, i.e. $U_{1 j} = U_{3 j}^*$ and $U_{2 j} = U_{4 j}^*$. I can't seem to come up with an argument why that would be a general feature of unitary matrices … Is it? If not, is there a name for these types of matrices?

Comment: Not aware of any special name, but when you try to unitarily diagonalise a 4x4 real skew-symmetric matrix over the complex field, the unitary (eigenvector) matrix you get has conjugate pairs of columns.

Comment: Thanks for this – do you have an insight as to why that is the case?

Comment: That's nothing special. A real skew-symmetric matrix often has distinct non-real eigenvalues. If this is the case, its eigenspaces are one-dimensional. So, its eigenvectors must occur in conjugate pairs because its eigenvalues occur in conjugate pairs. And its eigenspaces are mutually orthogonal if the matrix is normal.